# Removing all the lines starting with | in a text file using shell

Tags: shell

I need to remove all the lines starting with an symbol |  using shell
I have a text file which has some lines which starts with | and i need to remove it using shell

Example file

```
Example
Example of txt file

|I need to remove this
|I need to remove this too
```

I am new to shell can any one tell me how can i do that or give me some tutorial to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^|/d' filename > filename
```

Answer (score 0):

ugurarpaci's approach is good, but fundamentally flawed:

```
sed '/^|/d' filename
```

will produce the output you desire, but you cannot simply redirect it back to the file.  You can do several things:

```
sed '/^|/d' filename > new-file
sed -i '/^|/d' filename  # If your sed supports -i and you don't care
                         # about breaking hard links
sed '/^|/d' filename > tmp-file && mv tmp-file filename
```